# Spring profile automatically specified based on environment

Tags: java, spring

In Spring xml conf file I want that some configuration goes in prod environment and other configuration goes for non prod environments, for that I added the following

```
<beans profile="prod">
some code

<beans profile="!non-prod">
some code
```

All I want right now is that we get the right profile depending on the environment of the server that is running the application whether it is Prod or non prod, do you know how is that possible ?